# MediaWiki Docker container can't access MySQL Docker container

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, debian, mediawiki

I'm trying to create 2 Docker containers, one containing a MySQL database and another containing Apache/PHP and MediaWiki.  I'm using the latest images up on Docker Hub for MySQL and MediaWiki.

I'm creating the 2 containers using:

```
docker container run -d --name mediawiki --restart always -p 8080:80 mediawiki
docker container run -d --name mw-mysql -v mw-mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="Sup3rS3cret" -p 3306:3306 --restart always mysql
```

I'm not sure that I need to map the MySQL port (3306) since that's the default.  I'm also pretty sure that nothing is listening on port 80 so I probably don't need to map it to 8080 either.

I also create a network and add both containers to the network:

```
docker network create mediawiki
docker network connect mediawiki mediawiki
docker network connect mediawiki mw-mysql
```

From the host where Docker is running, I can fire up a mysql client and connect to the MySQL database running in mw-mysql.  If I log into the mediawiki container, I can ping the mw-mysql container.

The images are downloaded and created just fine but when I browse to the MediaWiki website at http://localhost:8080/ and start to configure MediaWiki, it can't connect to the database.

I've the following servers: "mw-mysql", "my-mysql.mediawiki", "localhost", "127.0.0.1" along with the userid "root" and the super secret password above.

I'm stumped.  I'm also new to Docker.  I must be doing something stupid but I just don't see it.  All suggestions gratefully accepted.

Comment: Did you try ```mw-mysql:3306```?

Comment: I used to be new to Docker. Then lost databases for dubious reasons, then quit docker...

Comment: @GabrielCiordas, I just tried that it did not work.  I got exactly the same error as before:

```Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. Check the host, username and password and try again. If using "localhost" as the database host, try using "127.0.0.1" instead (or vice versa).```

Comment: To this command: ```docker container run -d --name mw-mysql -v mw-mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="Sup3rS3cret" -p 3306:3306 --restart always mysql``` add this: ```--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password```

Comment: @GabrielCiordas I added that to the end of the docker container command and I still get the same error message.

On the MediaWiki Setup "Connect to database" page, I entered:
Database type: MariaDB, MySQL, or compatible
Database host: mw-mysql
Database name: my_wiki
Database username: root
Database password: Sup3rS3cret

I've even tried adding "default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" to the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and restarting the MySQL service in the mw-mysql container.  Nothing works.

Comment: Even if you don't know how to fix the problem above, do you have any suggestions on how to figure out what is happening between MediaWiki and MySQL?  I can connect to the MySQL container and enable the general log (but get no output).  I'm about to move over to the binlog using the mysqlbinlog command to convert the binlog file to an ASCII format piped to more.  All suggestions welcome!

Comment: @Tomasthanes Did you somehow resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with mediawiki: It is more or less like upgrading the DB (by reconfiguring the mw-config) but, this time, you will provide the `$wgUpgradeKey` from your LocalSettings.php current config file.

I re-ran the mw-config *http://server-name:8080/mw-config* and provided the `$wgUpgradeKey` and this regenerated the new LocalSettings.php (same as previous LocalSettings.php).

To view the LocalSettings, you can open a bash shell in the container and nagivate to /var/www/html.

```
docker compose exec mediawiki /bin/bash
```